# Forum not displaying 'all' results

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a table on a server that saves posts that users enter. On this final page where you can view them, you can choose to either view everyones result, or , pick just a certain weather to view. The picking certain weather part is working, but if you choose the 'all' option, it wont show anything. Any idea's why?

```
View Posts 
<br>
<form method="get" action="view_forum.php">
    <label>Select Weather to Filter </label><br />
    <select name="weather">
        <option value="all">all</option>
        <option value="cloudy">Cloudy</option>
        <option value="sunny">Sunny</option>
        <option value="windy">Windy</option>
        <option value="snowy">Snowy</option>
        <option value="mixy">Wintery Mix</option>
        <option value="rainy">Rainy</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="view" />
</form>

<div id="view">
    <center><img src="images/forum.png" width="589" height="97"></center>
</div>  

<div id="white">
    <div id="blue">
        <div id="grey">
            <div id="container">        
<?php

    $dbc = mysql_connect('html','user','password','database');
    mysql_select_db('database',$dbc);

    $weather = sanitize( $_GET["weather"] ); // keep your input clean

    if ( $weather == "all" ) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM stories ORDER BY id DESC";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM stories WHERE weather = '$weather' ORDER BY id DESC";
    }

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
        echo "<div class=\"names\"> {$row['name']}<br /></div>";
        echo "<div class=\"weathers\">{$row['weather']}<br /></div>";
        echo "<div class=\"stories\">{$row['story']}<br /></div>";
        echo "<img src=\"images/line.png\" width='800' height='3'>";
        echo "<br />";  
    }
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If `$_GET['weather'] == 'all'`, you need to remove the `WHERE` clause entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really watch out for sql injections, and if possible move over to  [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), or [PDO prepared](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
query's.

But your main problem is that your doing a query for `all` which unless you have weather called `all` it wont find it.

The solution is to check for the `all` option and change the query depending on that.

Also if `$_GET['weather']` is not set you need a default, I suspect you also have error reporting off and its not throwing a Notice:Undefined an error.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['weather'])){
    $_GET['weather']=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['weather']);
    //All
    if($_GET['weather'] == 'all'){
        $sql = "SELECT * from stories ORDER BY id DESC";
    }else{
        //Specific
        $sql = "SELECT * from stories WHERE weather='{$_GET['weather']}' ORDER BY id DESC";
    }
}else{
    //Default
    $sql = "SELECT * from stories ORDER BY id DESC";
}
?>
```

### UPDATE (Full code, with fixes):

```
<?php 
$dbc=mysql_connect('html','user','password','database') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('database',$dbc) or die(mysql_error());
?>

View Posts <br>
<form method="get" action="view_forum.php">
  <label>Select Weather to Filter </label><br />
  <select name="weather">
    <option value="all">all</option>
    <option value="cloudy">Cloudy</option>
    <option value="sunny">Sunny</option>
    <option value="windy">Windy</option>
    <option value="snowy">Snowy</option>
    <option value="mixy">Wintery Mix</option>
    <option value="rainy">Rainy</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="view" />
</form>

<div id="view">
 <center><img src="images/forum.png" width="589" height="97"></center>
</div>  
  <div id="white">
    <div id="blue">
      <div id="grey">
       <div id="container">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['weather'])){
$_GET['weather']=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['weather']);
    //All
    if($_GET['weather'] == 'all'){
        $sql = "SELECT `name`,`weather`,`story`
                FROM stories 
                ORDER BY id DESC";
    }else{
        //Specific
        $sql = "SELECT `name`,`weather`,`story`
                FROM stories 
                WHERE weather='{$_GET['weather']}' 
                ORDER BY id DESC";
    }
}else{
    //Default
    $sql = "SELECT `name`,`weather`,`story`
            FROM stories 
            ORDER BY id DESC";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<div class=\"names\"> {$row['name']}<br /></div>";
        echo "<div class=\"weathers\">{$row['weather']}<br /></div>";
        echo "<div class=\"stories\">{$row['story']}<br /></div>";
        echo "<img src=\"images/line.png\" width='800' height='3'>";
        echo "<br />";
    }
}else{
    echo 'No results';
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is also giving a error `"Warning: my_sql_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be a resource"`

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` and you need to make sure your connected before using it

Comment: This does show all the posts, but I'm still getting that error `Warning:mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be a resource.` I'm sure this is why its when i select single weathers to view it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: ok, as your only using the weather key just use `$_GET['weather']=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['weather']);`

Comment: This is another way to do it, yes. Sorry for being stupid...I'm new to php! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `WHERE` clause entirely if you select "all."

```
$weather = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET["weather"] ); // keep your input clean

if ( $weather == "all" ) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM stories ORDER BY id DESC";
} else {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM stories WHERE weather = '$weather' ORDER BY id DESC";
}

$result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
  /* Echo results */
}
```

Comment: hmm im getting a error, it saying the sanitize is a undefined function, i updated the code above. Im positive what u have is right! i probably just have it entered wrong.

Comment: @ChristineAustin `sanitize` is not a default function. It just means you need to make sure that the data you're putting into your query should be examined first.

Comment: @ChristineAustin Can you `echo $sql;` before running it and show us the query that it's running?

Comment: The problem is your not using `mysql_query($sql)`

Comment: @ChristineAustin Lawrence is right. You need to run the query. See my update in the answer above.

Comment: Ah yes, how stupid of me, sorry I'm new to php...but its amazing people like you that help me learn :]

Comment: @ChristineAustin You'll grow to love and adore Stack Overflow. Some of the smartest minds in the world congregate here.